# Accessing data from API json response. Arrays? Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to access the `steamid` data in a `json` response returned by an API, specifically the Steam API.

The responses look like this:

[image]

I've made it return json but why do I see `array` all over the place?

How would I access the `steamid` data? I'm getting a bit confused as I thought this would be json.

I'm using `guzzle` to get the data and converting it to json using the guzzle `json()` method:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is indeed using JSON to send/receive , however JSON is just a string, so in order to use that data PHP must parse it, which is automatically handled by guzzle, so as soon as you get the data back it has automatically decoded the data into a usable format for yourself.

It does this using the `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions.

You'd be able to access the `steamid` with the following.

```
// Assuming $data is your response from the API.
$players = array_get($data, 'response.players', []);

foreach($players as $player)
{
    $steamId = array_get($player, 'steamid', null);
}
```

Using the laravel helper `array_get()` function is a great way of ensuring you return a sane default if the data doesn't exist as well as eliminating the need to keep doing things like `isset()` to avoid errors about undefined indexes, etc. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers

Alternativly not using the laravel helpers you could use something similar to below, although I'd advise you add checks to avoid the aforementioned problems.

```
foreach($data['response']['players'] as $player)
{
    $steamId = $player['steamid'];
}
```

If you didn't want guzzle to automatically decode the API's JSON I believe you should just be able to call the `getBody()` method to return the JSON string.

```
$json = $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Beautiful answer! Is there an easier way to get the SteamID if I'm sure there will only be 1 player returned? Or would the `foreach` still be the best method?

Comment: If theres only ever going to be one player then you could just do `$steamId = array_get($data, 'response.players.0.steamid', null);`. Using the 'dot notation' you should be able to access any level of the array using the array helper functions.